# nginx - redirecting/rewriting url

Tags: nginx

so, this is the setup my work project has:
we have the backend of the main app and a separate service on the same server.
the https://main.app/api base url leads to the main backend while the https://main.app/api/service leads to the separate service. this is done through nginx, which has in its sites-available dir a "default" file, a "dev" file and some others (frontend related). the dev file is set up to redirect the /api/service request urls to the backend of the separate service while redirecting all other /api links to the main app backend. this was all previously set up by someone else and my contact with nginx is pretty much "I know it exists".

what I need is for the url https://main.app/.abcd/efgh/ijkl (ijkl is dynamic) to be redirected to https://main.app/api/service/efgh/ijkl, so basically to take the ".abcd" and replace it with "api/service" while also respecting the previous redirect rules about redirecting all /api/service links to the separate service backend.

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, first you rewrite the url and then you redirect:

```
    location /.abcd {
        rewrite ^/.abcd/(.+)$ /api/service/$1 break;

        // this is a previously set up redirect
        proxy_pass http://service;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```